# Listview with color and button android

Tags: java, android, button, android-listview, customization

I need to customize this listview, I wonder how I could do to put the buttons and an identifier of different colors to distinguish them.

Anyone know how it could be the xml? and how it could change colors ?? is there any component in android? or I could use an imageview to the colors?

[image]

I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a custom class, to create the Adapter for the List, and that class has to extend the `BaseAdapter` class. In this class, you have to implement the following methods:

- `public int getCount()`
- `public Object getItem(int position)`
- `public long getItemId(int position)`
- `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)`

In the last one, you can get a `LayoutInflater`, and load a view from `.xml`. In that `.xml`, you can define the layout of one row. Here's an example from one of my projects:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // menuItems is an ArrayList of Strings
    final String menu = menuItems.get(position);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) parent.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_mainmenu_row, null);
    TextView menuText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.menuListRow_menuItem);
    menuText.setText(menu);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I wanted to know was how to customize the listview to have a button and the distinctive colors, if not make a imageview or if there is a component in android.